# Shortcode for Twitter Bootstrap Collapse

Tags: shortcode, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to create shortcodes for [Twitter Bootstrap Collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse).

This is what Im trying to achieve:

```
[collapse-group]
  [collapse accordion="#accordionOne" title="my heading1"]some text[/collapse]
  [collapse accordion="#accordionTwo" title="my heading2"]some more text[/collapse]
[/collapse-group]
```

So for example 'my heading1' would show and 'some more text' would be collapsible.

Here is the code Im using, the last shortcode [collapse] is causing a server error on my local install.

```
function collapse-group( $atts, $content = null ) {  
return '<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">"'.$content.'"</div>';  
}  
add_shortcode("collapse-group", "collapse-group");

function collapse($atts, $content = null) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
    'accordion' => '',
    'title' => ''  
    ), $atts));  

return '<div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-parent="#accordion2" href="'.$accordion.'">"'.$title.'"</a>
        </div>
         <div id="'.$accordion.'" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">"'.$content.'"</div>
         </div>
        </div>';  
}  

add_shortcode("collapse", "collapse");
```

I know there are plugins but I'd prefer to have this custom made for this specific instance so I don't have to rely on a plugin with all sorts of other bloat. Im hoping an answer to this question would be useful to others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Use Collapse in Custom Post Type](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69274/twitter-bootstrap-use-collapse-in-custom-post-type)

Comment: After the answer from my previous question I realised I would need to use shortcodes, so I tried to create them as above but I got stuck. I'm sorry that you think this is a duplicate. I looked through the posts tagged shortcode and didn't really find anything to help me. This was helping me to get this far http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/wordpress-shortcodes-the-right-way/

Comment: Please add to your question details about "server error" part. What are actual error messages appearing and such.

Comment: Im running a local install using bitnami stack in Windows. I get the following error "Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly." When I remove the shortcode above from functions.php the error does not occur. I thought perhaps there was something wrong with my return function.

Comment: Please enable [debug output](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and see if that makes any error messages appear.

Comment: Thanks for the debug tip I changed the function name from 'collapse-group' to 'collapsegroup' and the server error goes away.

Comment: However when I put the shortcode on a page like this:
[collapsegroup]
[collapse accordion="#collapseOne" title="Test"]testing[/collapse]
[collapse accordion="#collapseTwo" title="Test2"]testing2[/collapse]
[/collapsegroup]

It just returns:

"
[collapse accordion="#collapseOne" title="Test"]testing[/collapse]

[collapse accordion="#collapseTwo" title="Test2"]testing2[/collapse]

"

Answer (score 2):

use `do_shortcode($content)` instead of `$content` in first function(collapsegroup)

Comment: That allows me to show the elements but the javascript is not working. The link for the title /?p=34558#collapseOne does not open to show the content as it does when I used the code from bootstrap site.